# How to start IE from .net application if IE is NOT a default web browser

Tags: internet-explorer, .net-3.5, clickonce

I have to start Click Once application programmatically and I am using URL to start deployment process. As we know web browser should be IE to do this task successfully ([FF+Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ffclickonce/) seems solve it also). 
How to start IE from .net application if IE is NOT a default web browser?

Maybe it is possible to do IE the default browser and then after installation switch back to previous one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is as simple as starting a process, setting the `Process.StartInfo.FileName` to "explorer" and passing in a parameter point to you your web address.  See the sample (C#) below:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "iexplore.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "http:\\\\www.google.com";
p.Start();
```

This will open Internet Explorer, and immediately load the website passed in as an argument.

Also, the `Process` class is part of the `System.Diagnostics` namespace.  Be sure to reference it at the top of your code file.

Comment: No problem, glad that I could help. :)

Comment: Does not work in Windows 8. Opens the default browser (Chrome in my case).

Comment: @AndrewGee: Interesting.  I don't have a Windows 8 PC to test this on, however, try to change the `p.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer";` line so that instead of "explorer" you input the full path to the explorer application.  If this doesn't work, you may want to ask a new question and explicitly state that this is strictly for Windows 8.  Also, please post a link to your follow-up question here.  I'm interested in the correct answer, if you find one.

Comment: @RLH I tried `p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Windows\explorer.exe";` but that gave me the same result (opened in Chrome). I ended up using this instead: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("IEXPLORE.EXE", MyURLHere)` which works in Windows 8.

Comment: @AndrewGee: I updated my answer to use `iexplore.exe` rather than `explorer.exe`.  I don't have a Windows 8 machine to test this code on, but it should have the same affect.  If you wouldn't mind, please post another comment letting me know if my snippet works or not.  If it doesn't, I'll update my post with an addendum for Win 8.

Comment: @RLH: `p.StartInfo.FileName = "iexplore.exe";` works on Windows 8!